# How to bind element attributes in backbone stickit?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I want to define an anchor tag href in my backbone stickit bindings, such that whenever a model attribute updates, the href of my anchor tag updates

Something like this,

```
bindings : {
    ".facebook-profile-icon('href')" : "facebook"
    ".twitter-profile-icon('href')" : "twitter"
}
```

Currently, I am doing something like this :

```
bindings : {
    ".facebook-profile-icon" : "facebook"
    ".twitter-profile-icon" : "twitter"
}

render : function(){
  this.stickit();
}
```

This just(understandably) updates the html of the classes instead of updating the hrefs.

Is there a way i can do this in backbone stickit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone.StickIt is well documented. In your case you want to update attributes, so you might use: 
https://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/#attributes